# Is there a printable version of posts in SE?

Tags: feature-request

Is there already a pre-defined feature in SE that allows one to print a post along with its answers and comments in a readable format? I have tried printing the page just via the browser, but it cuts through sentences and answers, and the outputs are usually very ugly (poor formatting). Since there are many many valuable and complete answers on physics.SE, it would be really nice if there was a print option that would keep the formatting of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed on [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stack-overflow-questions), you can try

> http://www.stackprinter.com/

All you need is the site name (Physics, in this case) and the question ID. The latter is found by clicking the link of the question and finding the number after `questions`, e.g.

```
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152937/what-am-i-doing-wrong-heredynamicsthey-should-give-the-same-answer 
                                           ^ here
```

And you can print it off. It does keep all the latex and images (the link I chose above I know has some images and latex and it looks fine in my print-view).